# Better way of writing this SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, where-clause, user-defined-functions

I have something similar to the following `WHERE` clause in my SQL statement:

```
AND (ipdp.UserID!=dbo.fn_userid(ipdp.ItemID) OR dbo.fn_userid(ipdp.ItemID) IS NULL)
```

However, I don't like how `dbo.fn_userid` function is being ran twice. How can I improve this line of code so that it only has to be ran once?

`ipdp.UserID` is always a Non-NULL Integer value

`dbo.fn_userid` can return a NULL or an Integer value

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure it's running twice? Does the function have side-effects or does it just repeatably map one value to another?

Comment: It's in my WHERE clause twice, so from my knowledge, it is running twice? The same parameter value is being passed both times so I'd like to cut down on this use.

Comment: In your code above the function will run twice only if the test inside the () is false.  Could you show som more of the where clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 AND ipdp.UserID != ISNULL(dbo.fn_userid(ipdp.ItemID), -1)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I had actually thought of doing something like this, but didn't know how efficient it would be. Thanks again